# why am I not able to open an emulator in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use flutter in VSCode but I am not able to set up the emulator. These are the errors that pop up.

[image]

Comment: These errors appear to come from the "Android iOS Emulators" extension. That extension is not required for launching/using emulators for Flutter development in VS Code, so you may want to try disabling it and using the functionality built-in to the Dart/Flutter extensions: https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-13/#emulator-launching

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are from middle eastern countries, you have to use vpn during running a flutter project in Vs Code.
maybe this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code) helps you.